# How to access repeating table field on SharePoint designer workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I am using SharePoint designer workflow 2013 in this I am not able to access the repeating table filed while i am publishing the form.On Select field or group.

[image] I am clicking on checkbox(Allow user to edit data in this field by using a datasheet or properties page) but it is showing default to me. So how I can access the repeating table field on SharePoint designer, so that I can do my operations like update etc.

[image]

On the below screenshot on update list item I am accessing the repeating table field but these not get access as red color in rectangular.Any idea how I can resolve this issues.